# Partitioning a usb

Tags: live-usb, gparted, iso

So what I'm trying to do is using `gparted` to create two partitions on my 32 GB USB stick. I want to create an Ubuntu ISO on the first partition and on the second I want to put some media files and various other files.

I've tried to do this before but when I tried to mount the second partition (which contains other data) I got an error message saying Ubuntu failed to mount as it can't read the second partition.

Comment: Wny not use the USB creator to set the space from there? (it has a slider to create room to store documents).

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: took a bit longer to find: http://askubuntu.com/questions/375153/usb-live-does-not-save-files-between-sessions see the slider in the 1st image

Comment: from my own experience, gparted won't work on partitioning usb, it's just me, I use disks https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gnome-disk-utility/

Comment: Check out the following link. http://askubuntu.com/questions/423300/live-usb-on-a-2-partition-usb-drive. Check out the marked answer in the link. I hope it can help you.

Comment: Why can i not mark this question as answered?

Comment: I've used gparted on USB drives successfully, and flash cards, HD's, looped files... gnome-disk-utility was actually a lot worse. @Druid There's no answers to mark correct yet... What's the mount error?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to partition your USB drive if you simply want some backed up files on the live cd. Just make a new folder called "backup" or "media" and put your files in it. Install like you normally would and when the installation is done, copy the folder onto your newly installed system.