# How do I create a live USB installer for UEFI/EFI systems that reads and saves persistence changes?

Tags: uefi, live-usb, 14.10, persistence

I have a 16 GB USB stick which runs a live boot of Ubuntu 14.10 with antivirus software installed which (obviously) needs to be kept up to date as I use it to boot and clean infected Windows machines.

To make it, I used *`usb-creator-gtk`* and an ISO for Utopic x64 Desktop downloaded from [The Official Site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and a 4 GB persistence file which *`usb-creator-gtk`* creates when the option is selected. Nothing fancy, nor anything complicated.

When this is used on BIOS systems, it's all there. I can update the antivirus software and the changes are saved in the user persistence file (*`casper-rw`* I believe) However, when used to boot UEFI systems, none of that is there and any changes made are not saved.

It's like I have two environments on this stick: The UEFI version which is the same as the default ISO, **DOESN'T** save changes and is R-O, and the BIOS version which has my tweaks and custom apps, **DOES** save changes and is R-W.

So - how I do get the UEFI version of the live environment to save any changes made or even better, how can I get the UEFI and BIOS versions of the live environment to share the same environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, specifically [bug 1159016](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1159016). The solution is described in this [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/375179/145754). Basically you just have to add the word `persistent` in `boot/grub/grub.cfg` after creating the live USB:

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

EDIT:

As you have a large 16GB drive, I would also suggest to split the USB drive into two partitions, a ~6GB FAT32 one for the live USB + persistence, and a 10GB `ext4` one for any other data you want to store on the stick. You could also use a separate partition instead of a casper-rw file if you need more than 4GB of persistence, but then `usb-creator-gtk` will not help you create it. (EDIT: see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/181062/145754) on how to do that.)

Unfortunately, when resizing FAT32 partitions you'll run into another bug ([bug #1313600](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1313600)), so I suggest you create the partitions manually (6GB FAT32, 10GB ext4) before using `usb-creator-gtk`:

1. Run GParted.
2. Format the whole USB drive, deleting all partitions.
3. Create a new FAT32 partition at the beginning of the drive, with a size of ~5500MB.
4. Create the live USB using the FAT32 partition with `usb-creator-gtk`.
5. Finally, as I am running an UEFI system I needed to fix [this bug](https://askubuntu.com/a/375179/145754) as well by adding the word `persistent` in `boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

   ```
   menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
       set gfxpayload=keep
       linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
       initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
   }
   ```

Comment: I located [THIS POST](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138356/how-do-i-get-a-live-usb-to-use-a-partition-for-persistence) as well which enabled me to use that alternate partition you suggested the persistence instead of using the `casper-rw` file.