# How do you use persistence in UEFI mode?

Tags: uefi, live-usb, persistence

When booting a LiveUSB into UEFI mode, persistence is not available. When booting into legacy mode, it works fine. why? And how may I resolve this?

Comment: How did you set the persistence?

Comment: @VRR By using LiLi to create the bootable usb with ~100mb of persistence, and then deleting the file and creating an ext4 partition named casper-rw.

Comment: Can you use LiLi to even create bootable USB drive for UEFI? I don't think so. If you want persistence read this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media) at 2.3.

Comment: I know what I'm booting in UEFI mode, I see the UEFI splash screen. It looks different from the legacy boot. I've tried those methods, and they don't work any different from what i've done.

Comment: I wasn't able to create bootable USB using Lili for UEFI and there is no info about it on their site. Maybe you have combo UEFI BIOS . Others gain persistence using this [method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577833/how-do-i-create-a-live-usb-installer-for-uefi-efi-systems-that-reads-and-saves-p) involving `Startup Disk Creator` , but I find the app buggy.

Comment: LiLi just copies the ISO contents to the disk - same as if I were to make a UEFI bootable flash drive on my own. And, Yes, I have a hybrid bios, with legacy and UEFI boot options. Booting legacy mounts and uses the 13gb persistence partition, while booting UEFI does not.

Comment: @VRR I just did so, and it works fine. Persistence does not mount in UEFI mode.

Comment: Persistence will not mount if Lili refer to syslinux and not Grub2. If Lily is just copying files then yes USB should mount, but it also change the references of the casper file when you set the persistence. I believe those references are linked to syslinux but I will doublecheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to create USB Live CD with persistence is to manually form the partitions using GParted.

This is what I've done:

- Format your USB  with GPT partition table (though, I believe MBR should work fine as well).
- Create two partitions. First is for ISO files and it should be FAT32 (~1100MB for Ubuntu 14.04). Second is for persistence and it should be ext4 with label **casper-rw**.
- Copy files from your ISO (including hidden) to USB FAT32 partition.
- Edit `boot/grub/grub.cfg` and just add the word **persistent** *(This is the reason why persistence doesn't work for you in UEFI mode.)*:

> `menuentry "Start Kubuntu" {
>
>           set gfxpayload=keep
>
>           linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi`persistent`file=/cdrom/preseed/kubuntu.seed boot=casper maybe-ubiquity quiet splash --
>
>           initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
>
>       }`

It might be a little slow when you first start it especially if you use USB2.0.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed how Ubuntu's performance is primarily based on (At least in my experience) disk speed. When loaded into ram, even on older computers, Ubuntu runs much faster when on a 5400 rpm drive or a usb 2.0 flash drive. I recently got a 250gb ssd which has drastically improved performance. I have an fx-8320 overclocked to 4.4 ghz, and a faster storage system improved performance

Comment: Yes, that is the bottleneck of every OS. Just take note that it has been stated that not every USB 3.0 work well with Ubuntu (not by my experience) at the time being. In case you want to buy one.