# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS live USB stops working after initial software update

Tags: uefi, 16.04, live-usb, inspiron, initramfs

*Afterthought: with 16GB to work with, does it make more sense to just install full Ubuntu onto the USB, instead of running live with persistent storage?

Steps to replicate my problem:

1. From Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, download the ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso and verify md5sum.
2. Run Startup Disk Creator and put the iso on a brand new and erased Sandisk Cruzer Glide 16GB USB stick, with 4GB for persistent use.
3. Fix the grub persistency issue for UEFI machines, a la [USB-live does not save files between sessions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375153/usb-live-does-not-save-files-between-sessions/375179)
4. Boot onto a Dell Inspiron 13 7000 series laptop using one of the USB 3.0 ports.
5. Set up wireless and change time/date settings.  Reboot, and confirm the changes are permanent.
6. Run Software Updater and do the initial set of upgrades.
7. Reboot, select grub option 'Try Ubuntu without installing' as usual, then get error after the ubuntu progress dots cycle through white and red several times:

> Blockquote

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.

I tried both the USB 3.0 and 2.0 ports with the same outcome.

Comment: Why are you rebooting after settting up wifi during install? I don't understand.

Comment: The point of the reboot was to make sure the settings were persistent.  They were not, the first time around, and then I found the fix for UEFI machines.  It has nothing to do with the end state.

Comment: Might be related to how persistent storage was set up. Can you please try again using UnetBootin https://unetbootin.github.io/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I've abandoned the Live USB for now, and installed full Ubuntu 16.04 onto the USB and it runs fine. I found that other problems (and possibly this one) are solved by using Startup Disk Creator from an existing Ubuntu 16.04 installation, instead of a 14.04 installation, which was my originally posted attempt.